# Move from VS Team Service to an on-premises TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops

We have projects on the VS Team Service. What we want is to move those projects to TFS 2015.

How it can be done?

I [found this site](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/move-vso-premises-tfs/), but it was in 2014. The Microsoft email address is no more valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to move from VS Team Services to Team Foundation Server or to export a project or project collection in such a way that it can be attached to a TFS server.

Depending on what features of VS Team Services you're using it may be possible to migrate some of the data to a new target environment with relative ease. And depending on what you're willing to lose you may be able to migrate some other bits easily as well.

There are 3rd party tools that offer migration to and from VS Team Services, though these can be pretty expensive.

**Easy to migrate**:

- Git source control repositories (`git clone --mirror` followed by `git push` to the new server)
- TFVC data (using Timely Migration)

**With dataloss (relatively) easy to migrate**

- Work item data without relationships, history and attachments (through Excel)
- TFVC Version control data (latest version only)

**Hard to migrate**

- TFVC with history
- Work items with history
- Work items with relationships and links to other artefacts
- Test results
- Builds
- Releases
- Package management (not available on-premise)
- Full trace-ability data

### Tools

Tools that may be of use to you are:

- Team Foundation Server Migration Tools

  - If it works, great, if it doesn't it's very painful to get it to do what you want
  - Doesn't migrate builds, releases, build definitions, work item tags, work item configuration (area, iteration, kanban), security among other data.
- OpsHub Integration Manager

  - personally I've had very mixed experiences with this tool. It can be painfully slow (as in 15 days to migrate source control only)
  - doesn't migrate builds, releases, build definitions
  - and is very expensive
- Timely Migration

  - One of the best source control migration tools for TFS.
  - Doesn't migrate anything other than TFVC data

There is a Data import option under way, to make it easier to migrate to Visual Studio Team Services but nothing has been announced around exporting tem projects in order to attach them to TFS on-premise.