# Migrating from Visual Studio Online to On-Premises TFS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

How can one migrate from Visual Studio Online to an on-premises instance of TFS (version 2017)?

Ideally I'd like to migrate all code, project management data, etc.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without the use of third-party tools, all of which will result in some amount of data loss.

Answer (score 1):

> There is currently no way to move from VS Team Services to Team
>   Foundation Server or to export a project or project collection in such
>   a way that it can be attached to a TFS server.
>
> Depending on what features of VS Team Services you're using it may be
>   possible to migrate some of the data to a new target environment with
>   relative ease. And depending on what you're willing to lose you may be
>   able to migrate some other bits easily as well.
>
> There are 3rd party tools that offer migration to and from VS Team
>   Services, though these can be pretty expensive.

Refer to this thread for details: [Move from VS Team Service to an on-premises TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488596/move-from-vs-team-service-to-an-on-premises-tfs)

Comment: @Chris K. Is that answered your question? Any update?